# mysql select query 1 of the multiple values in selected field

Tags: php, mysql

I had another form to upload the details of 1 product which have multiple values (10) but let's say we choose New Arrival, Black, White and upload to database. So right now my database will have the field name as 'category' which has the values New Arrival, Black, White.

Now I want to do a search function but whenever I try running it, it just won't display the result. So i made 2 records where:

1st record with field category and value 'New Arrival'
2nd record with field category and value 'New Arrival, Black, White'

When I try running my code again, it did return the result of the 1st record and I tried duplicating the same records for a few rows and it turns out that it can only return the result where the category field has only 1 value.

Below is just a brief part of my code:

My add record form input for the category field is:

add_new.html

```
<select name="category[]" size="10" multiple="multiple">
<options>New Arrival</options>
<options>Black</options>
<options>White</options>
</select>
```

add_process.php

```
$category = implode(", ", $_POST['category']);
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO products_list (category) VALUES ('$category')";
```

search_form.html

```
<input type="text" name="search_text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

search_process.php

```
$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_category']);
$select = mysql_query("select image1, image2, image3, image4 from products_list WHERE category IN ('new arrival') ORDER BY id ASC");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)) {

    echo $row['image1'];
    echo $row['image2'];
    echo $row['image3'];
    echo $row['image4'];

}
```

To repeat my question, how to get the result of the rows that contains the (desired value) in that category field?

Next question is, the category value is stored as 'New Arrival' only in the database, how do I get the return result if I were to type 'arrival' only instead of the full name? Currently it won't return any result too if I were to type only 'arrival'.

Hope you guys understand what I'm trying to say. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Only one search keywords of the category or could be more than 1 search keywords?

Comment: Suggest to use like. Eg,  `code`where
category LIKE '%new arrival%' `code`

Comment: Hi Sel, it works!! Thanks!! Even works if I just put 'arrival' but it won't work again if I put %arrival white black%. Btw, it can be more than 1 search keyword.

Comment: For more than 1 keywords, you could use OR `code`WHERE category like '%new arrival%' OR category like '%black%'`code`

Comment: Sorry, didn't specify clearly. If it's getting the input from an input text? And if there's space in between those search keywords, does it affect or anything?

Comment: in PHP, can be done as below:
`code`
$catsearch = $_POST["category"];
$keywords = explode(' ', $catsearch);
$keywordsBits = array();
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    $keyword = trim($keyword);
    if (!empty($keyword)) {
        $keywordsBits[] = "category LIKE '%$keyword%'";
    }
}


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products_list WHERE ".implode(' OR ', $keywordBits)."); 

`code`

For you quest, what do you meant by space in between ? is that one keywords or two keywords?

Comment: The space I meant was a few keywords like : "white(space)black(space)new" in the search text. So total there will be 3 individual word to parse into the query to return the result. Hope you understand.

Comment: You could play around with the php code i provided above. The delimiter of the search keywords lie at `code`$catsearch = $_POST["category"]; $keywords = explode(' ', $catsearch);`code`

Comment: LOL, I've actually wanted to ask you to explain what those means. Anyway, I've tried your code above and it doesn't work, no response. I will try and play around with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easier reference, i put the explanation here.

```
$catsearch = $_POST["category"]; 
$keywords = explode(' ', $catsearch);  //if keywords entered is "white black new", will convert to array of "white","black","new". The delimiter here is the space.
$keywordsBits = array(); 
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) { 
          $keyword = trim($keyword); 
          if (!empty($keyword)) { 
                $keywordsBits[] = "category LIKE '%$keyword%'"; 
          } 
} 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products_list WHERE ".implode(' OR ', $keywordBits));
```

This will result a query like

```
SELECT * FROM products_list WHERE category LIKE '%white%' OR category LIKE '%black%' OR category LIKE '%new%'
```

If you want to separate the keywords by ",", you could use

```
$keywords = explode(',', $catsearch);  //if keywords entered is "white,black,new arrival", will convert to array of "white","black","new arrival". The delimiter here is the comma.
```

Thanks.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. Am trying to solve the query string as you had 1 more " in the string and still can't get it right.

Comment: Shd be `implode(' OR ', $keywordBits));`

Comment: Hi Sel, I finally got it working. It's actually .implode(' OR ', $keywordBits)); Anyway, thanks for your great help!! =)

Comment: Hi Sel, just realised that if I want to search in different fields, how do I code it? E.g: SELECT * FROM products_list WHERE category LIKE %something% OR new_arrival LIKE %something% Is that possible?

Comment: yup.Do you meant this?`$keywordsBits[] = "category LIKE '%$keyword%' OR new_arrival LIKE '%$keyword%'"; ` This will result something like `SELECT * FROM products_list WHERE category LIKE '%white%' OR new_arrival LIKE '%white%' OR category LIKE '%black%' OR new_arrival LIKE '%black%' `

Comment: YES!! I tried to edit the code but I keep getting it wrongly. Like parsing them into variables.

Comment: 1 more thing is that the $keywords can only limit to 1 type of delimiter? Is it possible to do different kinds of delimiter? =x

Comment: different kind of delimiter meaning `black,red;white` something like this? and you want `WHERE category LIKE %black% OR category LIKE %red% OR category LIKE %white% `?

Comment: For the delimiter, it's something like what you mention as I do not know what will the user will input. For the search keywords it's something like WHERE category LIKE '%$keyword%' OR new_arrival LIKE '%$keyword%'. Thanks for your help again. =D

Comment: I think its better to specify to users what delimiter to separate the keywords. There could be many possibilities for the delimiter if one is not specify.

Comment: Suggest to put a label above the search keyword textbox. `Separate search keywords or phrases using a comma.`

Comment: I see. Thanks for the suggestions!! As for the search conditions, do I put everything into 1 variable which is the $keywordsBits[] ?

Answer (score 1):

Sel says:

```
$select = mysql_query("select image1, image2, image3, image4 from products_list WHERE category like '%new arrival%' ORDER BY id ASC");
```